# PHP - MySQL no error message on SQL errors

Tags: php, mysql

I'm expecting the following code to produce an error in PHP, but it runs without any sign of error.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

$link = mysql_connect('localhost','JUST_ANY_TEXT EVEN WITH SPACES', '');

mysql_select_db('JUST_ANY_TEXT EVEN WITH SPACES', $link);

echo 'LINK RESULT = '.($link?'OK':'ERROR'); //THIS PRINTS: LINK RESULT = OK

echo mysql_query("SELECT INVALID_TEXT FROM TABLE_THAT_DOES_NOT_EXISTS_ANYWHERE PLUS ANY TEXT 3[t3p36g333 3 4638343´tp4oy0i9u54t-9u´089hwpjoeg~,ç");
```

Comment: Does it at least show a warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works as intended. If you check out the [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) you will see that there is a return value form most of the functions. You should check that return value to make sure everything is fine.

Also these legacy `mysql_*` functions are quite outdated. I would suggest using the [PDO package](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

To point out the immediate error in your code. You should use it like:

```
$success = mysql_select_db('JUST_ANY_TEXT EVEN WITH SPACES', $link);
if (!$success)
    die ('Error selecting the database!');
```

Comment: mysql_connect and mysql_select_db returns TRUE (mysql_connect returns the resource id). only the mysql_query results FALSE.

Comment: I agree, try using the mysqli functions

Comment: @vbence, `$success` value is FALSE. This solves my problem!
But, is there a way to know when `mysql_connect` fails?
Or I got to try to select a database for this?

Comment: @DMF From `mysql_connect`'s documentation:  Returns a MySQL link identifier on success or FALSE on failure.

Comment: I know, but any username I use, it returns MySQL link identifier.

Comment: @DMF Then it seems like either MySQL accepts anything or the real connection is not made until you actually try to run a query.

Comment: It wasn't like that in the past. Older PHP versions would complain when a query failed. Not anymore it seems. It is understandable, but it would also be understandable to have a way to revert to the old behavior for development/testing. Is there any such way?

Comment: @Rolf If you are using up-to-date APIs you can set this behaviour. With PDO you can do: `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to get an exception on SQL errors.

Answer (score 1):

For the mysql_query() you have to check the result of mysql_query() and use mysql_error() to get the MySQL error message:

```
$query  = "invalid query";
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$query);
```

However, mysql_connect() should raise an error in case of wrong credentials.
Are you sure you can see errors occurred? Whatever PHP errors?

Comment: then check your credentials if they are really such "ANY TEXT WITH SPACES". Both mysql_connect and mysql_select_db raises a regular PHP error. However, you still can use mysql_error() if you don't sure.

Comment: Now I realized that mysql does not throws error only for the username parameter. The others parameters such as servername and password, throws error when using wrong credentials.

Comment: @YourCommonSense, Wow, is [colonel](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294329/632951) back?